# Randomizer for baseball positions

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications

I'm a web designer with a good amount of knowledge in html and css.  I have some js knowledge, mainly just basic site interaction.  I teach my son's T-ball team and the league has asked me to make a tool on their website to randomly assign positions and batting order for the team.  This needs to be random for every player but not repeating a position in the lineup or fielding position until everyone has been in all of them.  I need it to make sure everyone has an equal amount of time in every spot.

The coach would go to the league website go to the lineup/position tool put in there team names and then a lineup and position assignments would be generated and could be saved as a pdf.

I need this to be saved so that the next week the players wouldn't get the same position or spot in the lineup.

I know this is a lot, whatever help I get would really be appreciated. 
Thank You!

Comment: Sounds like a fun App to build, but you have a lot of requirements here. Have you started on the JavaScript? Do you have a server-side App running with a Database for persistence? If so, if you can post some code, with specific questions, it would be easier to provide assistance. I'd be willing to help you write the App, but it probably would be best done through email correspondence -vs- posting here.

Comment: I have only prototyped the app i will write the html/css tonight and put it on codepen.  As far as the javascript im really not sure where to start, I just need some direction. I'm not js clueless just never done anything lime this, hoping to learn alot. Email correspondence would be fine lavoiect@gmail.com thank you for your help

Comment: Cool. Post the link to your Codepen App when you have it. I'll drop you an email.